# String with accent crashes SHA256 encryption

Tags: ios, objective-c, hash, sha256

I want to create hash from a string. If the string has characters with accent (like é, ő), it crashes with NSASCIIStringEncoding. It doesn't crash with NSUTF8StringEncoding, but on the server it doesn't match.

```
+(NSString *) getSHA256FromString: (NSString *)clear {

    const char *s=[clear cStringUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];// NSUTF8StringEncoding works, but isn't the same on server
    NSData *keyData=[NSData dataWithBytes:s length:strlen(s)];

    uint8_t digest[CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH]={0};
    CC_SHA256(keyData.bytes, keyData.length, digest);
    NSData *out=[NSData dataWithBytes:digest length:CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    NSString *hash=[out description];
    hash = [hash stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    hash = [hash stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@""];
    hash = [hash stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""];
    return hash;

}
```

Comment: You should use UTF-8 in your case, both iOS and server. What is your code on server side?

Comment: Server uses UTF-8. I didn't write the server code, and I can't access it. It's a .NET server.

Comment: ... and don't use `description` to convert NSData to a hex string. `description` is only for debugging purposes, the format is not officially documented (as far as I know) and might change.

Comment: Perhaps it is a composed vs decomposed characters issue (I am just guessing). You could try `s = [[clear precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping] UTF8String]`, more simply, `NSData *keyData = [[clear precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`.

Comment: @MartinR It still doesn't match.

Comment: @McDermott: OK, it was just a guess. But `NSUTF8StringEncoding` should be the correct encoding to choose if the server uses UTF-8.

Comment: I tried that, but it is the same.